# Finding whether the coordinate is within polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, location, latitude-longitude, google-location-services

I want to know if the given coordinates (lat & lon) is within given 4 coordinates.

[image]

i.e., If i have the lat,lon of A,B,C,D and E and i wanted to check if E lies within A,B,C and E.

How can i do that ?

I tried to see this example from [Google Map Coordinates LatLngBound class - contains](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds.contains).

The example i can see is like

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.69726685890506,-2.7379201682812226),
    new google.maps.LatLng(55.38942944437183, -1.2456105979687226)
);
var center = bounds.getCenter();  // still returns (55.04334815163844, -1.9917653831249726)
var x = bounds.contains(center);  // now returns true
```

It has only 2 coordinates, like A&B. Hows that possible without having C&D's coordinates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because this is using `LatLngBounds` which creates a rectangle, not a polygon. If you have two corners of a box, the other two corners can be assumed. You just need to specify the opposite corners. In your example you just need to send either A and D or B and C as a pair, the other two can be ignored. If you need a polygon then you want to create [a polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygons) and then get determine if it contains the point with `google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, polygon)`.

[`containsLocation()` Documentation here](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#containsLocation).

[Full example here.](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)

Comment: Hey thank you for the explanation , now i got the point.. So i will pass SouthWest and NorthEast alone